Forcing Node.js to Use System OpenSSL with LD_PRELOAD
I am working on a use case where I need to override the certificate used during TLS connections by injecting a custom certificate through the SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations function from OpenSSL. I have successfully implemented this solution in a Python application using LD_PRELOAD to override the OpenSSL function at runtime.
However, the same approach is not working with Node.js. After some research, I found that Node.js embeds OpenSSL internally rather than relying on dynamically linked OpenSSL libraries. As a result, it seems that my LD_PRELOAD trick is ineffective. I am looking for a way to force Node.js to use the system-installed OpenSSL (shared library) instead of the embedded one, without rebuilding Node.js from source.
Below are the details of my setup and what I have tried so far.
C Code to Override SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Function pointer to hold the original SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations function
int (*original_SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations)(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *CAfile, const char *CApath) = NULL;

// Custom SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations function
int SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *CAfile, const char *CApath) {
    // Load the original function if it hasn't been loaded yet
    if (!original_SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations) {
        original_SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations = (int (*)(SSL_CTX *, const char *, const char *))
            dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations");

        const char *error = dlerror();
        if (error != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error loading original SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations: %s\n", error);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    const char *my_CAfile = "/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/Lima-workspace/gk_workspace/tls-ebpf/sample-apps/keploy.crt";
    printf("\n\nOverriding CAfile with %s\n\n", my_CAfile);

    // Call the original function with the overridden CAfile
    return original_SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, my_CAfile, CApath);
}

How I Compile the Code
clang-14 -I/usr/include/openssl -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -fPIC -shared -o ssl_override.so ssl_override.c -lssl -lcrypto

Node.js Code
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();
const CERTIFICATE_PATH = '/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/Lima-workspace/gk_workspace/tls-ebpf/sample-apps/ninja.crt';

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: fs.readFileSync(CERTIFICATE_PATH), 
  keepAlive: false,
});

app.get('/catFact', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact', { httpsAgent });
    res.status(200).json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'SSL certificate validation failed',
      details: error.message
    });
  }
});

const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://0.0.0.0:${PORT}`);
});

How I Run the Node.js Application
LD_PRELOAD=/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/Lima-workspace/gk_workspace/tls-ebpf/tls-change-cert/ssl_override.so node index.js
What I Tried by referring Force node.js to use non-distro copy of OpenSSL.

LD_PRELOAD with Multiple Libraries:
I tried using both OpenSSL shared libraries and my custom override library in LD_PRELOAD.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 \
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 \
/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/Keploy/Lima-workspace/gk_workspace/tls-ebpf/tls-change-cert/ssl_override.so"

node index.js


Using lsof to Verify Loaded Libraries:
I confirmed that both my override library and the system’s OpenSSL libraries are loaded into the Node.js process.

➜  lsof -p $(pidof node) | grep ssl
node  507762 gouravkumar  mem REG 0,40  70040 /path/to/ssl_override.so
node  507762 gouravkumar  mem REG 254,1 737192 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3


Result:
Despite confirming that the libraries are loaded, the printf statement in the overridden SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations function is not being called. This suggests that Node.js is not invoking the function at runtime, possibly because it relies on its embedded OpenSSL implementation rather than the dynamically linked version.

What I Need Help With
How can I force Node.js to use the system-installed OpenSSL shared libraries (like libssl.so.3 and libcrypto.so.3) instead of the embedded version?

Is there a way to ensure Node.js dynamically loads the system’s OpenSSL without rebuilding it from source?

Are there any known workarounds or configurations (like setting specific environment variables) to achieve this?


Process versions in Node.js:
➜  tls-support git:(main) ✗ node -p "process.versions"        
{
  node: '18.20.4',
  acorn: '8.11.3',
  ada: '2.7.8',
  ares: '1.28.1',
  base64: '0.5.2',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cjs_module_lexer: '1.2.2',
  cldr: '44.1',
  icu: '74.2',
  llhttp: '6.1.1',
  modules: '108',
  napi: '9',
  nghttp2: '1.61.0',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0',
  ngtcp2: '1.3.0',
  openssl: '3.0.13+quic',
  simdutf: '5.2.4',
  tz: '2024a',
  undici: '5.28.4',
  unicode: '15.1',
  uv: '1.44.2',
  uvwasi: '0.0.19',
  v8: '10.2.154.26-node.37',
  zlib: '1.3.0.1-motley'
}


Why do you try to add the CA location in such a strange way of patching OpenSSL and then trying to enforce the use of your own build? Why not simply use the normal API in the application to set the CA location?

Lets assume i don't have the access of application source code and just have the running command for that case i can't set the CA in the application. I want to get the decrypted traffic anyhow. I explored https://github.com/gojue/ecapture but it is not working for node then thought of using LD_PRELOAD. In my usecase i am acting as a man in the middle. And it fails in case of certificate pinning.

If you just want to use a different CA file - why not simply replace the CA file the application uses with your own (same filename, different content) instead of trying to hijack SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations? And if the application is doing real certificate pinning (by enforcing specific certificate or pubkey) than simply providing a different verification path would not work anyway.

I don't know anything about the application, don't know the exact file name also. If the application is doing real certificate pinning in case of python application i was able to use the same setup without changing anything in the application and change the certificate.

"don't know the exact file name" - use strace to find out what files the application accesses.

Okay, let's break down your question into two:

Using system-installed OpenSSL
Overriding the certificate

Using system-installed OpenSSL
Indeed, OpenSSL is statically linked, Node.js does not use the system-installed OpenSSL libraries at runtime. This design choice means that you cannot easily override or replace the OpenSSL version or its configurations used by Node.js without rebuilding it from the source, at least to my understanding.
Here is how you can build node: https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-build-nodejs-with-openssl
Thanks, Patrick!
However, if you need only override the certificate, there are ways to do it:
Overriding the certificate
1 The simplest way would be to leverage
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTSenvironment variable:
`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/custom-ca.crt node your-app.js`

This will just extend the list of trusted certificates you can use
in your app.

2 Monkey-patch the tls method:
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

// Read your custom CA certificate
const customCa = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/custom-ca.crt');

// Store the original method
const originalCreateSecureContext = tls.createSecureContext;

// Override the method
tls.createSecureContext = function (options = {}) {
  // Ensure 'ca' is an array and include the custom certificate
  options.ca = options.ca || [];
  if (!Array.isArray(options.ca)) {
    options.ca = [options.ca];
  }
  options.ca.push(customCa);
  
  // Call the original method with modified options
  return originalCreateSecureContext.call(tls, options);
};

3 Inject it into https lib programmatically
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// Read your custom CA certificate
const customCa = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/custom-ca.crt');

// Create an HTTPS agent that includes your custom CA
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: customCa,
});

// Use the custom agent in your HTTPS request
https.get('https://example.com', { agent: httpsAgent }, (res) => {
  // Handle the response
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});


In case you can't access the source code, I would then rather create a docker image with prebuilt node with system openSSL baked into node and test it out

Okay, i will try using docker images approach, NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS didn't work as i already tried it before. 2nd and 3rd approach requires code changes which doesn't work in my case.

But, how can i find the prebuilt node with system openssl. Sorry for asking as i couldn't find any and thought of building the node with system openssl

Try this out, I also updated the answer itself:
https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-build-nodejs-with-openssl

Thanks Pavlo Sobchuk but i was able to build the node with system openssl but somehow node is neither calling SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations nor SSL_do_handshake, maybe it is still using embedded openssl. Please see this https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4493

Hmm, thanks for the reference, interested in the resolution as well. Maybe will try to build it myself too later today
